# "Do forgive me"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, do

Good morning everyone, I am an English learner and I am reading "Dracula" by Bram Stoker.
I have a little question regarding this sentence:

> "Oh, do forgive me for being so rude" pronounced by Jonathan.

What's the difference between the same sentence without the verb "**do**"?

I mean "Oh, do forgive me for being so rude" vs "Oh, forgive me for being so rude"

Correct me if I made a mistake. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English declarative sentences we can make a sentence emphatic by stressing the auxiliary verb:

- I can speak English.
- I *can* speak English.

If the original sentence doesn't contain an auxiliary, we insert the dummy auxiliary *DO*:

- I like elephants.
- I do like elephants.

Imperative sentences in English do not usually have an auxiliary verb. There are two scenarios in which we need one, and have to use *DO* support. The first is if we want to negate the imperative:

- Move!
- Don't move!

The second is if we want to make the imperative emphatic:

- Excuse me.
- Do excuse me.

Notice that using *do* in this way often makes the imperative more beseeching and less order-like. It can be seen as a polite form. However, this isn't always so, as you can see below:

- Be quiet.
- Do be quiet.

**The Original Poster's Question**

- Oh, do forgive me for being so rude.

The speaker here has used *do* to make the imperative emphatic as a sign of politeness.